# How to enable the compiler option -Wobjc-signed-char-bool-implicit-int-conversion to generate warnings for implicit BOOL conversions at compile time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon

I wanted to check if any warning showing in my project for implicit BOOL conversions at compile time where I can fix for **Apple Silicon** support. Apple mentioned in below document for enabling the compiler option -Wobjc-signed-char-bool-implicit-int-conversion to see those warnings. Can you help me where I can enable this option? I don't find such option in project settings or scheme settings.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_silicon/addressing_architectural_differences_in_your_macos_code

Answer (score 1):

You can do this per target, but also for the whole project. The targets inherit from the project but can be customised as well. Anyhow, select your project (the top node in the tree view) and then select **Build Settings**.

[image: build settings]

Now you will see something like this if you scroll down and search enough. You can either set it as a custom flag (similar to the *-Wno-unused-getter-return-value* in the image) or you can set it if it is available as one of the Warnings just below the custom flags, it seems to be the *Implicit Boolean Conversions* warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via build settings as stated by skaak.

If you would prefer pragma declarations you can define:

#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wobjc-signed-char-bool-implicit-int-conversion"